# sendBroadcast is only sending once in a while loop

Tags: android, multithreading, while-loop, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

I'm downloading an Image in a Thread which was started in a Service. Everything is working fine but i want to show the progress in a ProgressBar within my MainActivity/UI Thread. I want to do this via broadcast messages. As you can see in the Code below i'm calling the sendBroadcast method in a while loop on the Service where i started the thread. Its working but only once in the last cycle when the image is fully downloaded. So the Progressbar shows 100% in the end. My question is: Why is it only called in the end and what can i do about it?

Edit: I have to use Broadcast Messages. It's an university exercise.

The relevant Code in the Thread:

```
    URL url = null;
    int fileSize = 0;


    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(src);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        fileSize = connection.getContentLength();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("LOG", "URL not found");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("LOG","Couldnt get Size of the file from this connection - No File found");
    }
    try {
        is = url.openStream ();
        byte[] byteChunk = new byte[1024];
        Intent progressIntent = new Intent();
        progressIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.UPDATE_PROGRESSBAR);
        int n;
        int currentSize = 0;
        while ( (n = is.read(byteChunk)) > 0 ) {
            currentSize = currentSize + n;
            baos.write(byteChunk, 0, n);
            progressIntent.putExtra("imgName", imgName);
            progressIntent.putExtra("progressValue", (int) ((currentSize/fileSize)*100));
            runningService.sendBroadcast(progressIntent);
        }
```

My Receiver:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

MainActivity main;

public Receiver(){};

public Receiver(MainActivity main){
    this.main = main;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.TRANSFER_BYTEARRAY)){
        byte[] byteArray = intent.getByteArrayExtra("imgBA");
        String imgName = intent.getStringExtra("imgName");
        main.setDownloadedImg(byteArray,imgName);
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.UPDATE_PROGRESSBAR)) {
        String imgName = intent.getStringExtra("imgName");
        int progressValue = intent.getIntExtra("progressValue",0);
        main.updateProgressBar(imgName, progressValue);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I have some idea what happens, but just as a quick fix: if you instantiate your intent inside the loop, does it help?

Comment: No - doesnt help. Just tested it :/

Comment: Ok. So what likely happens is you handle progress on the same thread that does the download, so your updates are not guaranteed to be seen on the thread that renders UI. Use `Activity.runOnUIThread` for stuff where you need to update something on UI.

Comment: Are you sure about this? In my main activity i start a service which starts threads to download picutures. The threads are sending the broadcast messages. The receiver is registered on the UI-Thread... So i handle the progress in The UI-Thread dont i?

Comment: If that really is the case and it still doesnt work, then it could be a bug in some computation.

Comment: It is. But the UI-Thread is the main-activity is it that what you're talking about? I'll try to put the progress bars in a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to not send so many broadcast messages. It would be more professional if you could use the observer pattern for this. [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm) is well explained how to use it.

Basically there is 3 steps:

1. You have to create an interface, which contains one method for updating the progress bar:

   ```
   public interface ProgressChangeListener{
       void onProgressChanged(int percent);
   }
   ```

   If your MainActivity handles the progress bar, then the interface should be implemented by the MainActivity.
2. When you instantiate the thread, where you download the image, you have to pass a `ProgressChangeListener` type object which basically will be your MainActivity, which implements this listener.
3. Finally, when the progress value changes, you simply call the `onProgressChanged` method of that object in the thread.

This solution will work better than the broadcast messages and it's much more elegant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's an university exercise and i have to use boradcast messages. If i wouldnt have to i would have used AsyncTask i guess. Ill add this to my Question.

Comment: @L.Rex, You actually do have to use AsyncTask, I'm pretty sure. If progress is updated on the same thread that renders UI, the UI would not show any progress until the very last update, which looks roughly what you have right now.